# How to set height of button inside a container in flutter

Tags: flutter-layout

I tried to google but I think in theory this should work or Container sets always its height and width to child? What is wrong here in the code? I would like to use container not other widget.

```
Container(
    width: 150,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
    height: categoryHeight,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange.shade400, borderRadius: 
    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
    child : ButtonTheme(
        height: 50.0, // **not working why container is not showing!!![enter image description here][1]**
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),

        child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: const Text('Enabled Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
        )
    )
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below code and read this beautiful article , thank you

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

```
container(
   child:Center(
         child:ButtonTheme()
   )
)
```

Comment: It works thank you. Seems container has fixed size not constraints ranges so child gets the same. Center takes the same size as container but allows child to be smaller. Its all in docs and I tried the code.